# If an item in a list is selected, then print a specific string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Bit of a beginner here. I want my code to return a specific string if a specific item from a list is selected.

```
import random

# carrots
# yarn

list = ['bunny', 'kitty']

random.choice (list)
```

So if say `'bunny'` is selected, then I want it to post:

> bunny - carrots

But i don't want "bunny" to ever be paired with anything other than "carrots", so no "yarn". How do I go about this?

Comment: What do you mean by "paired with"?  What have you tried?  StackOverflow is generally for questions about some *specific* problem or error.  It's not (unfortunately) for general programming tutorial/guidance.  That said, if you can clarify your question a bit I can point you in the right direction.

Comment: As in bunny pairs with carrots and kitty pairs with yarn

Comment: Have you learned about `if` statements yet?  Have you learned about dictionaries?

Comment: Nope, i'm just staring out now

Comment: I suggest continuing your Python learning--once you learn more you'll be able to answer your own question with clarity.  The [python tutor](https://mail.python.org/mailman/listinfo/tutor) mailing list is a good place to get additional help and direction.  For your own problem, I think a dictionary would be a good start so at least get through the chapter on that in whatever Python learning resource(s) you're working from.

Comment: Thanks i will :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the pairs of items in a dictionary, and then select an item using one of its keys:

```
import random

# pair the items in a dictionary
items = {'bunny': 'carrots', 'kitty': 'yarn'}

# get a list of the keys in the dictionary
keys = list(items.keys())

# select a key
key = random.choice(keys)

# print the key and what it is paired with
print(key + ' - ' + items[key])
```

Comment: Thank you this was just what i needed

Comment: @Jonny. You're welcome. (PS: please mark this answer as accepted - i.e. click the tick symbol).